# MongoDB check types of attributes before insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to define the following schema:

```
var toySchema = new Schema({
    id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: Number
});
```

I believed that when I inserted into the collection using db.toys.insert(), mongo would check to see that the type of each attribute matched the types in the schema, but it seems that it does not. For example, id should be a string, but I was able to insert a document with an integer id. How can I enforce the schema onto these inserts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work, but not as you might expect. If you specify a field in your model that is of type `Date` and you try to save a boolean value (e.g. `true`) then you will get an error like

```
Error [ValidationError]: MySchema validation failed: expireAt: Cast to Date failed for value "true" at path ...
```

The reason for your particular problem can be found in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings)

> If you pass an element that has a toString() function, Mongoose will call it, unless the element is an array or the toString() function is strictly equal to Object.prototype.toString().

You could add a [custom validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators)

Comment: I was also able to insert a document that does not contain the correct attributes and has less attributes than the schema asks for. Am I supposed to enable validation somehow?

Comment: Did you omit the `price` attribute?

Comment: I actually something that looks like {type: "hi}. It had none of the required attributes but still inserted without error. Very weird

Comment: I've tried it locally and I get an error as expected if I omit a required field. What version of mongoose and mongo are you using?

Comment: Mongo version is 3.6.3, mongoose is 5.9.13

Comment: How are you saving the document? Add in your question the code you use